# MySQL error from an IF statement

Tags: php, mysql

The email query below is supposed to be triggered by a field called "ttemail" being 0. When I try to use it, I am getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1`.

It appears that the email is sending out for the at least the first username where ttemail = 0.

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
if($row["ttemail"] == 0){
    $mailaddress = $row['email'];
    $link1 = "<a href='http://www...com/page.php'>Page Title</a>";
    $message1 = "Congratulations, message.

                <br>
                <br>

                More Message

                <br>
                <br> 

                Please click the link below to see more.
                <br>
                <br>

                $link1
                ";      

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Website Name <no-reply@website.com>" . "\r\n";

    $queryem = mail($mailaddress, "Congratulations, message 
                            $submission.", $message1, $headers);

    //$ttquery = sprintf("Update login SET ".$row['ttemail']." = '1' WHERE username = ".$row['username']."");           

    mysql_query($queryem) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($ttquery) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? You're using the return value of a call to `mail()` as an MySQL query???

Comment: You want to use a boolean as query?? =P

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday and didn't I ask you in that question to please show the generated queries instead of the meaningless PHP source code?

Comment: I want to send out an email when the IF statement is true.

Comment: $queryem = mail($mailaddress, "Congratulations, message 
                        $submission.", $message1, $headers);

Comment: @John that doesn't make any sense, does it? A boolean value as a query?

Comment: That doesn't even begin to make sense. mail() returns a bool, not a query. Go through the logic of your function, step by step, and think about what you wrote there.

Comment: Okay, maybe that's my problem.  Let me look into it.

Comment: Plus, you should have to check if `$row['ttemail']` is equal to _0_ if your first `select` query was good.

Comment: @Chouchenos: okay... how is that done?

Comment: @John : I don't know since you're not giving the `select` query to begin with. But I bet you could add a `WHERE ttemail = 0` in it, so your result won't have to be sorted with PHP.

Comment: @John: looking at this (and other questions of yours), you have a problem with [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). Rather than the outdated mysql driver, use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), as prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to injection. If you need a tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html).

Comment: @John: (cont) There are other kinds of injection out there; research them. Any time you interpolate user input into a string that then gets interpreted in some fashion, you have the potential for injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a ' in your where clause. Check the corrected query below -

```
$ttquery = sprintf("Update login SET ".$row['ttemail']." = '1' WHERE username = '".$row['username']."'");
```